# ERROR: Failed building wheel for RPi.GPIO (MacOS)

Tags: python, installation, package

I am trying to install RPi.GPIO 0.7.1 and consistently get the following error lines (full error output shown at end)

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for RPi.GPIO
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for RPi.GPIO, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have python version 3.11.2
I have pip version 23.2.1
I am running macOS Ventura 13.2 on a 16-inch 2018 MacBook Pro with Graphics: AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 4 GB, Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB, Memory: 16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4, Storage: 1Tb

Additionally, I have received this error when attempting to install a different package (although this was a while ago and have forgotten what I was trying to install) and could not find a solution then either. I don't believe I have changed my python or pip version since then.

Here is the full output from trying to install RPi.GPIO:

```
pip3 install RPi.GPIO
Collecting RPi.GPIO
  Using cached RPi.GPIO-0.7.1.tar.gz (29 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: RPi.GPIO
  Building wheel for RPi.GPIO (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [37 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/RPi
      copying RPi/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/RPi
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/RPi/GPIO
      copying RPi/GPIO/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/RPi/GPIO
      running build_ext
      building 'RPi._GPIO' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/source
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c source/c_gpio.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/source/c_gpio.o
      source/c_gpio.c:170:9: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') from 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
          if ((uint32_t)gpio_mem % PAGE_SIZE)
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      source/c_gpio.c:171:34: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') from 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
              gpio_mem += PAGE_SIZE - ((uint32_t)gpio_mem % PAGE_SIZE);
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      2 warnings generated.
      source/c_gpio.c:170:9: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') from 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
          if ((uint32_t)gpio_mem % PAGE_SIZE)
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      source/c_gpio.c:171:34: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') from 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
              gpio_mem += PAGE_SIZE - ((uint32_t)gpio_mem % PAGE_SIZE);
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      2 warnings generated.
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c source/common.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/source/common.o
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c source/constants.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/source/constants.o
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c source/cpuinfo.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/source/cpuinfo.o
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c source/event_gpio.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/source/event_gpio.o
      source/event_gpio.c:24:10: fatal error: 'sys/epoll.h' file not found
      #include <sys/epoll.h>
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for RPi.GPIO
  Running setup.py clean for RPi.GPIO
Failed to build RPi.GPIO
ERROR: Could not build wheels for RPi.GPIO, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have tried installing RPi.GPIO, expecting a proper install, however I get the error that `Failed building wheel for RPi.GPIO` when I try `pip3 install RPi.GPIO`. I have tried updating python and pip, still resulting in failures. I have read various Stack Overflow threads on this topic, seemingly unable to find a solution which works for me.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks,
Ian

Comment: I have exactly the same problem (python 3.11, RPi.GPIO-0.7.1, MacOS 14.2.1)